# Ajax POST to PHP session variables - cant see what is wrong with this

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, session-variables

I have a PHP script which uses Jquery to store a PHP SESSION variable.

The script says "Hooray it worked", but the session variables GotTheUserTZ and UserTimeZone are not stored - because when I reload the page, I keep getting "Undefined index: UserTimeZone" from the line:

```
echo $_SESSION['UserTimeZone'];
```

I cannot figure out the issue.

Thanks :)

```
<?php

    // HTML HEADER AND BODY CODE IN ANOTHER FUNCTION

    session_start();

    // ALL OF BODY HTML OUTPUTTED HERE

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

if (!isset($_SESSION['GotTheUserTZ']))
{
?>  
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function() {
        var gmtRe = /GMT([\-\+]?\d{4})/;
        var d = new Date().toString();
        var tz = gmtRe.exec(d)[1];

    request = $.ajax({
        url: "<?php echo $GLOBALS['SITEURL'].'storetimezoneajax.php' ?>",
        type: "POST",
        data: "vv="+tz
    });

    // Callback handler that will be called on success
    request.done(function (response, textStatus, jqXHR){
        // Log a message to the console
        alert("Hooray, it worked!");
    });

    // Callback handler that will be called on failure
    request.fail(function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
        // Log the error to the console
        alert(
            "The following error occurred: "+
            textStatus, errorThrown
        );
    });

        });
        </script>   
<?php   


    echo $_SESSION['UserTimeZone'];
}

?>

    </body>
</html>
```

and the storetimezoneajax.php in the same directory:

```
<?php

$_SESSION['GotTheUserTZ'] = "yes";

$_SESSION['UserTimeZone'] = $_POST['vv'];

?>
```

I'm running on localhost if that makes a difference.

Comment: In your `storetimezoneajax.php`, you need a `session_start();` before setting the session variables. If you set session variables without starting the session, the values will be thrown away at the end of the request since it will just be as any other array.

Comment: On your HTML-page, you are checking that if `$_SESSION['GotTheUserTZ']` is _NOT_ set, then you're trying to echo `$_SESSION['UserTimeZone']`, which, obviously won't be set either.

Answer (score 0):

Change your data parameter for this

data : {
 vv : tz 
}

and try again.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all your responses. It was the missing session_start() as suggested above that was the problem.